# Neither Nitrogen or FEH Work in Autostart if Xrandr also in Autostart

Tags: screen-resolution, wallpaper, autostart, awesome-wm

If I put nitrogen --restore in awesome config file lua.rc, the desktop opens with the correct wallpaper.  However, if I add xrandr to config file the resolution is successfully set but nitrogen no longer works.  Instead I get a black screen and neither my preferred wallpaper or the default awesome wallpaper.  The same happens with feh instead of nitrogen.  The order of the two applications makes no difference.  I left my config file in /etc/xdg/awesome instead of putting it in my home directory.  Any solution?

I tried nitrogen alone - it works correctly.

Of course xrandr alone works correctly.

With both in autostart section of config file only xrandr works.

Changing the order makes no difference nor does using feh instead of nitrogen.

I want both the screen resolution and the wallpaper to be set when started up.

Comment: How exactly are you starting them in `rc.lua`? Does something like `awful.spawn.with_shell("xrandr --whatever ; nitrogen --restore")` make a difference? (That way they really run one after the other)

Comment: That didn't work but the following did:do
  local autostarts =
  {
    "safeeyes",
  }

  for _,i in pairs(autostarts) do
    awful.spawn.easy_async_with_shell(
      'ps -C '.. i ..' |wc -l',
      function(stdout, stderr, reason, exit_code) 
        gears.debug.dump(stdout)
        if tonumber(stdout) or 0 < 2 then
          awful.spawn(i)
        end
      end
    )
  end
end